# "luaL_openlibs identifier not found", but all other luaL calls work (using C++ & lua library)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lua, luabind

I am having trouble tracking down the source of this error because all other Lua appears to be compiling fine.

My scriptManager class is like so:

```
#include <luabind\lua_include.hpp>
//skip some
LuaScriptManager::LuaScriptManager()
{
   state = luaL_newstate(); //is recognised fine
   luaL_openlibs(state); //will not compile with this not commented
}
```

Luabind\lua_include.hpp is like so:

```
#ifndef LUABIND_CPLUSPLUS_LUA
extern "C"
{
#endif
   #include "lua.h"
   #include "lauxlib.h"
   #include "luaconf.h"
#ifndef LUABIND_CPLUSPLUS_LUA
}
#endif
```

I don't believe I am missing any #include files that would apply to LuaL_openLibs. However, I didn't set up the lua files for this, someone else on the team did. Does anyone know any potential causes for this, or is my best bet to nuke it and set up the lua include files from scratch?

Comment: This seems a link problem, not a compilation problem related to missing includes.

Comment: Gibet - I'm not 100% since I didn't set up the project. Would you be able to point me in the direction of instructions for the pre-5.1 version of openlibs to check?

Comment: In newer Lua versions, `luaL_openlibs` seems to be defined in `lualib.h`, so try including that one & see if it works.

Comment: That was it! Didn't realise luabind's lua_include was missing that. Cheers!!